# How do I apply Euler' theorem on a nonplanar graph?

Tags: graph-theory, eulerian-path

How do I apply Euler's theorem (faces+vertices-edges=2) to a nonplanar graph to prove that it is nonplanar?

Comment: You could use the consequences of Euler theorem's:
$E \le 3V - 6$ , that could gives you that graph is nonplanar, but that's not show that graph is planar.

Comment: But Euler's isn't an if-and-only-if theorem...

Comment: So, this is not criterion that graph is planar or not

Comment: But you could say that graph isn't planar using Euler theorem and consequences.

Comment: Can't you only say that if there's an only-if case?

Comment: I could say so:
if graph is nonplanar, then Euler theorem doesn't work for it.

Comment: This is not true, Euler characteristic can be extended to graphs that can be embedded on other shapes, not only planes. See my answer for more details...

Comment: The only criterion that is necessary and sufficient to prove that a graph is planar is : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski's_theorem

Comment: Kuratowski's theorem and Wagner's theorems, yes. I'm working on the Petersen Graph, where the consequences hold even though the graph is nonplanar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Euler's characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic) is a function of the genus.

$$\chi=2-2g$$

Roughly speaking, the genus is the number of holes in a shape.

For example, for a plane, the genus is 0 (no holes), and thus $\chi_{plane}=2$

And any planar graph must satisfy
$$|V|-|E|+|F|=\chi_{plane}=2$$

Lets take for example $k_5$ (the complete graph on 5 vertices) which is not planar.

But, we can draw it on a [torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus) like this:

[image: k5 on a torus]

$$|V|-|E|+|F|=5-10+5=0$$

Which is exactly $\chi_{torus}=2-2*1=0$